# Positioning rotated image on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple drag'n'drop editor for making mockups of t-shirts with prints, using html5 canvas. The issue I've come across, is that once I rotate an image, which for the time of rotation is a simple div with a background-image, I try drawing it on canvas, relying on position and rotation of this div and observe a dislocation depending on the angle.

If the angle is 0deg, the image in drawn without any dislocation, comparing to the div's position.

[image: Positioning div]

[image: 0 degrees angle]

But, if the rotation is different from 0, the position changes.

[image: Div containing image]

[image: Dislocated print]

Here is the code, drawing prints, stored as objects, based on drag'n'drop div's size, position and rotation.

```
load_print: function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    if (this.Drag._clone === null) return;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var width = self.Drag._clone.width();
        var height = width * img.height / img.width;
        var rotate = parseFloat(self.Drag._clone.attr('rotate')) || 0;
        var left = self.Drag._clone.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().left - 
                    self._print_canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        var top = self.Drag._clone.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top - 
                    self._print_canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        self.save_print(img, left, top, width, height, rotate);
        return (typeof callback === 'function' ? callback() : null);
    };
    img.src = this.Drag._clone.css('background-image').replace('url("','').replace('")','');

},

save_print: function(img, left, top, width, height, rotate) {
    console.log(left, top);
    this._prints_arr.push({
        img: img,
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        rotate: rotate
    });
},

draw_prints: function() {
    console.log('drawing');
    this.Drag.destroy();
    this._print_canvas_ctx.clearRect(
        0, 
        0, 
        this._print_canvas.width, 
        this._print_canvas.height
    );
    for (var i in this._prints_arr) {
        this._print_canvas_ctx.save();
        this._print_canvas_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        this._print_canvas_ctx.translate(
            this._prints_arr[i].left + this._prints_arr[i].width / 2,
            this._prints_arr[i].top + this._prints_arr[i].height / 2
        );
        this._print_canvas_ctx.rotate(this._prints_arr[i].rotate);
        this._print_canvas_ctx.drawImage(
            this._prints_arr[i].img,
            -this._prints_arr[i].width / 2,
            -this._prints_arr[i].height / 2,
            this._prints_arr[i].width,
            this._prints_arr[i].height
        );
        this._print_canvas_ctx.restore();
    }
},
```

How can I fix the positioning of rotated images on canvas?